# SQL Server trigger IF condition on other table

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, triggers, conditional-statements

In SQL Server, is possible to trigger an event based on a `SELECT` condition in another table?

Let's imaging this trigger in `TABLE_1`:

```
FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (ID, COD_CAT) 
       SELECT COD_ART,'X3' 
       FROM INSERTED
```

This trigger works fine and always.

I would like trigger that insert event only if `INSERTED.COD_ART` does not already exist in `TABLE_2`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use trigger on table1 and use 'if exists' before insert

```
...
FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN
IF not EXISTS 
(SELECT COD_ART,'X3' 
FROM INSERTED A LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 B    
ON A.COD_ART = B.COD_ART
WHERE B.COD_ART IS NULL)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (ID, COD_CAT) 
       SELECT COD_ART,'X3' 
       FROM INSERTED
END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a selective trigger but you can insert selectively. Use `LEFT JOIN` to insert only non matching rows as below.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (ID, COD_CAT) 

SELECT COD_ART,'X3' 
FROM INSERTED A LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 B    
ON A.COD_ART = B.COD_ART
WHERE B.COD_ART IS NULL
```

Comment: If i do this no record are inserted in TABLE_2.